WPF how to extend UserControl Resource Style
I built a UserControl based on a DataGrid in order to add filtering which I don't detail. It is quite complex, but works well (I'll have to figure out how to remove lots of code-behind later on).
I would like to extend some styles (each control which uses this UserControl will have its own converters to change how the row are displayed with separators etc.) but I get the following error:
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance.
<DataGrid x:Class="CustomDataGrid">

    <DataGrid.Resources>

        <!--  Data Grid Row Header  -->
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

            <!-- I would like to use the specific ControlTemplate (e.g. add row separators) defined in the control which uses this UserControl -->

        </Style>

    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Style>

        <!--  DataGrid  -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">

            <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}" />

        </Style>

    </DataGrid.Style>

</DataGrid>

    <controls:CustomDataGrid>

        <controls:CustomDataGrid.Resources>

            <!--  Data Grid Row Header  -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

                            <!-- Border, SelectiveScrollingGrid and DataGridCellsPresenter included in the ControlTemplate with specific value converters, etc. -->

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

            </Style>

        </controls:CustomDataGrid.Resources>

    </controls:CustomDataGrid>


In your last XAML, shouldn't the TargetType be DataGridRowHeader? Are you asking how to assign a custom row header template to your CustomDataGrid? DataGrid has the RowHeaderTemplate property for this purpose. The client of your CustomDataGrid can simply set the CustomDataGrid.RowHaderTemplate property. You shouldn't try to set it from within the CustoDataGrid. Consider it a client-side customization. Although it's very likely that I misunderstood the problem.

Thanks for your comment. Yes, I removed Header from DataGridRowHeader, etc it was a typo. I think you understand my question correctly. I read somewhere that I can't redefine a Style from the client as it collides with the UserControl one. I'm also trying to use a DependencyProperty just to bind the ControlTemplate like <Setter Property="Template" Value="{Binding DataGridRowStyleControlTemplate}" /> but I get some weird issue  The property 'DataGridRowStyleControlTemplate' was not found in type 'CustomDataGrid'.

I think you shouldn't set the DataGrid.RowStyle internally if it contains mandatory configuration. You must expect that the style is overridden externally. However, a Style in general is applied cumulative in that the external Style is merged into the default Style. But UserControl does not have a default style. For this reason CustomDataGrid should be a custom control that extends DataGrid and defines a default style in Generic.xaml. This way you can set defaults in the Style and allow the client code to defien its own Style e.g. to set a custom template.

Regarding the error, it looks like the dependency property is registered for the wrong type (not typeof(CustomDataGrid)).

To sum it up, convert the UserControl to a custom control and set defaults in the default style that is defined in Generic.xaml. Then the client code can define its own style to define the template. If you add a DataGridRowTemplate dependency property, then bind to this property from within the default style setter using {TemplateBinding}. This enables the client to optionally define the template using the DataGridRowTemplate in addition to defining a Style. This is a good example to show how custom controls allow more flexibility when it comes to customization.

Do you like to have an example?

You should convert your control to a custom control that defines a default Style in Generic.xaml. This way, the client of your control can define a Style without removing your defaults set by your internal Style.
This way the client can provide the ControlTemplate for the DaraGridRow simply by defining a custom Style. This will be an alternative to the DtaGridRowTemplate property that you have introduced.
It's also more robust to register a dependency property changed callback with the CustomDataGRid.DataGridRowTemplate property that delegates the new ControlTemplate to the CustomDataGrid.Template property. This link between the two properties is a crucial link. You don't want this link to be broken when the client defines a Style that sets OverridesDefaultStyle to true. This will be the case if this link is established from a Style (that's a perfect example why code-behind is really necessary - because you were saying in your question that you will have to remove all code-behind from your control).
The fixed and improved version of your control could look as follows:
CustomDataGrid.cs
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridRowTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(DataGridRowTemplate),
    typeof(ControlTemplate),
    typeof(CustomDataGrid),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public ControlTemplate DataGridRowTemplate
  {
    get => GetValue(DataGridRowTemplateProperty) as ControlTemplate;
    set => SetValue(DataGridRowTemplateProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly RoutedCommand ColumnHeaderFilterCommand
    = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ColumnHeaderFilterCommand), typeof(CustomDataGrid));

  static CustomDataGrid()
  {
    // Register the default Style for this control
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid)));
  }  

  public CustomDataGrid()
  {
    var columnheaderFilterCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      ColumnHeaderFilterCommand, 
      ExecutedColumnHeaderFilterCommand, 
      CanExecuteColumnHeaderFilterCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(columnheaderFilterCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteColumnHeaderFilterCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    object commandParameter = e.Paramter;
    e.CanExecute = true;
  }

  private void ExecutedColumnHeaderFilterCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    object commandParameter = e.Paramter;

    // TODO::Execute header click action
  }

  protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
  {
    if (element is DataGridRow dataGridRow
      && this.DataGridRowTemplate is not null)
    {
      dataGridRow.Template = this.DataGridRowTemplate;
    }

    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
  }
}

Generic.xaml
Add a Themes folder to your project root. Then add a XAML ResourceDictionary file to this folder and name the file Generic.xaml.
<ResourceDictionary>

  <!-- 
    The default Style for CustomDataGrid. 
    Unless an external Style sets OverridesDefaultStyle to TRUE, 
    external styles will be merged into the default Style. 
    This way you don't have to be afraid of external Styles. 
  -->
  <Style TargetType="CustomDataGrid" 
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">

    <!-- Set defaults here -->

    <!-- For example, set the default template for the `DataGridRow` -->
    <Setter Property="DataGridRowTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <Controltemplate TargetType="DataGirdRow">
           ...
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Set up the ColumnHeader using routed commands -->
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle">    
      <Setter.Value>  
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
          <Setter Property="Command"
                  Value="{x:Static CustomDataGrid.ColumnHeaderFilterCommand}" />
        </Style>
      </Setter.VAlue>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

Now the client can either set the template by defining a custom Style, which will no longer break your internal default style, or by setting the DataGridRowTemplate property.

Sorry, I'm still unsure about how to define the default ControlTemplate of the DataGridRowTemplateProperty dependency property. I want to keep the default style of the CustomDataGrid as it is inside its XAML. Furthermore this style contains another style for the DataGridColumnHeader which contains callbacks such as DataGridHeaderFilterToggleButton_Click (to deal with the popup to filter the columns). Later on, I would like to do the same with a ContextMenu with common Refresh and Reset methods which I extend specifically for some CustomDataGrid such a CenterCurrentDate.

I have updated the example to show how to set the DataGridRow default template. "I want to keep the default style of the CustomDataGrid as it is inside its XAML" - Sorry, could you explain to me what you mean, please? I have also added an example that shows how to setup a routed command for the DataGridCVolumnHeader.Command to replace the event. In general, use routed commands or routed events. Both can be handled on the parent CustomDataGrid.

Another option is to use named template parts, and then from the CustomDataGrid.OnApplyTemplate method override call GetTemplateChild("elementName"). Then you can configure this element. That's the common pattern to add behavior e.g. event handlers or commands to the template: use routed commands and routed events. They will bubble up to the CustomDataGrid. Here you can handle them. Register routed commands and routed events in the constructor.

So, for your ContextMenu you have to follow the above example and implement a set of routed commands that you then can use like shown above to set  MenuItem.Command property. I hope this helps. If something is not clear please feel free to ask.

Thanks you for your explanations, but I'm afraid I still need to rework a few things (most specifically remove all the code-behind I wrote for CustomDataGrid)..

Ok, too bad the example wasn't very helpful. I was really trying to address your provided requirements. But why remove code from code-behind and where do you move it to? Everything is exactly where it belongs.
